# How to load a git branch from another R package

Tags: r, git, package, refactoring

In R, how I load one package's git branch from another package?

There are two packages, call them *producer* and *consumer1*.  I am refactoring my code by moving a bunch of function definitions and tests from *producer* to *consumer1*.

I'm creating git branches, *rfctrProd* and *rfctrCons1* for *producer* and *consumer1*.  In *rfctrCons1*, I need a statement doing something like

```
#` @import producer, gitBranch = rfctrProd
```

Also, I'll to do similarly with other packages which import *producer*, to make sure I haven't broken them either. (I *think* the functions I'm refactoring are only used by *consumer1*, but I want to be sure before I merge my changes.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use roxygen comments to specify the import branch, just the functions themselves. You can specify the branch in the DESCRIPTION file, under `Remotes:`. Assuming it's Github (the default), you can do:

```r
Remotes:
  username/producer/rfctrProd
```

If it's not Github, have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html) for the other syntax.

Comment: @caldwelist, thanks, I'll try that.  But I'm surprised.  I use Github, but I hadn't pushed _rfctrProd_ yet.  I was expecting _rfctrCons1_ to point to the local copy of the _rfctrProd_ branch.

Comment: You can use a local branch instead, look at the link I provided for details.

Comment: I appreciate the link and the detail.  The 'Devtools dependencies' page you reference sure _looks like_ it answers my question.  But I haven't been able to get it to work.  I'm going to start over with a new post and explain what I've tried and what hasn't worked.   
  But your pointers have at least gotten me closer to an answer.