# R: Loading git branches from other pacakge's git branch

Tags: r, git, git-branch, r-package

(I started this conversation in [How to load a git branch from another R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461900/how-to-load-a-git-branch-from-another-r-package), but never could get it to work.  Coming around with new detail.)

I'm *trying* to set up a pair of R packages, each with a development git-branch, so that the master imports the master, and the dev imports the dev.  All code is built and stored locally.

I have built two 'toy' R packages, as sub-directories of *~/lab*. The first package, _puppies, _ has two git branches, *master* and *fido*.  It has
one function `whoIsAGoodDog()` which prints a message.  In *master*, `whoIsAGoodDog()` messages *'ARF! Main Branch'*. In *fido* it messages *'BARK! fido branch'*.

My second R package is *animals*, which imports *puppy*, and with two git branches, *master* and *mammals*. Its single function `talkAnimal()` calls `whoIsAGoodDog()`.  The behavior I want to see is:

- When I'm in *animals/master*, `talkAnimal()` should message *'ARF! Main Branch'*
- When I'm in *animals/mammals* `talkAnimal()` should message *'BARK! fido branch'*

The article https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html appears to answer my question.  But editing the DESCRIPTION file in *animals/mammals* to read

```
Imports: puppy
Remotes: local::/home/myAccount/lab/puppy@fido
```

Doesn't work.  Both branches of *animals* import whichever branch of *puppies* I've built most recently.  I've messed around with the syntax of the `Remote:` to no avail, trying

```
Remotes: local::/home/myAccount/lab/puppy#fido
Remotes: local::/home/myAccount/lab/puppy/fido
Remotes: local::lab/puppy@fido
```

and so on, restarting R and running `$ git commit` to *animals/mammals* after each change. And I've changed the DESCRIPTION in *animals/master* similarly.

No joy; the only thing that seems to matter is which branch of *puppies* I built most recently.

Ideas?  Have I misunderstood the `Remote:` syntax, or is there something else entirely?

Other details: I'm running R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20), in RStudio Server.  In both branches of *animals*, the code is

```
#' @import puppy
#' @title Talk to the Animals
#' @export
animalTalk <- function(){
  whoseAGoodDog()
}
```

@caldwellst helped with the first round.